# Compare two arrays value one retrieved from database and other stored in local

Tags: php

```
$countt = 0;
if ($row[0] == $userinput1){ $countt++;}
if ($row[1] == $userinput1){ $countt++;}
if ($row[2] == $userinput1){ $countt++;}
if ($row[3] == $userinput1){ $countt++;}
if ($row[4] == $userinput1){ $countt++;}
echo @$countt;
```

Above is code which i am looking foreward to compare. but it is giving 5 as output even i select wrong options.

Comment: We need more details here. What is the value of `$row`? Of `$userinput1`? What is "wrong options"?

Comment: $sql1="SELECT * FROM questions LIMIT 1 OFFSET $a";
     $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
     echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      echo "" . $row["id"]. ". " . $row["question"]. "<br/>";
      echo "<input type='radio' value='A' name='option'>" 
                .$row["option1"]."<br>";
      echo "<input type='radio' value='B' name='option'>" 
              }
                $userinput1 = $_POST['option'];

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in_array()`

```
if(in_array($userinput1, $row)) {
    $countt++;
}
echo $countt;
```

Comment: Here Both $userinput1 and $row are array. $userinput1 is array which saves the option value the user selects and $row is fetching answers from database.

Comment: Exactly, so `$userinput1` is a value or a string and not an array whereas `$row` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 $countt = 0;
    switch ($userinput1) {
        case row[0]:
            $count++;
            break;
        case row[1]:
            $count++;
            break;
        case row[2]:
            $count++;
            break;
        case row[3]:
            $count++;
            break;
        case row[4]:
            $count++;
            break;
    }
    echo $count;
```

Comment: guyss here i am developing a quiz in which options and question are selected from database. then when the user select options for all questions and click on submit then answer from database is fetched and is compared with user input saved in an array. if the user input matches at zero index matches with answer fetched from db at zeroth index then count will increase. problem here is comparing two array.please tell a proper way for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that `$row` is an array, you could iterate over it, then compare each value with the input:

```
$countt = 0;

foreach ($row as $column) {
    if ($column === $userinput1) {
       $countt++;
    }
}
```

Not sure what `$row` looks like for you, though.